# File Name Issue with Retina Sprite Kit Exports from TexturePacker

Tags: sprite-kit, texturepacker, texture-atlas

I seem to be having an issue with exporting retina resolution atlases from TexturePacker.

Using the Sprite Kit data format and AutoSD, my low res textures have the name format "exampleTiles.1.png", and my retina textures have the format "exampleTiles@2x.1.png". Xcode doesn't seem to be able to automatically load retina resolution atlases, presumably because of ".1" appended after the "@2x". I suppose I couldn't manually edit the texture name and plist path, but this would be tedious to do after every publish.

Other info that might (or might not) be relevant:
Texture Settings: Atlas Bundle: /DirectoryPath/exampleTiles@2x.atlasc
AutoSD Settings: Main Extension: @2x
AutoSD Settings: Other Size: Scale: 0.5, Extension: (blank)

Please let me know if there is any more information that I can provide to clarify. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why does the .1 get appended? You should get rid of it any way you can.

Comment: I think the ".1" is similar to how Sprite Kit's naming convention works for atlases that may contain more than one actual .png file, but still share one .plist file. The main difference is that Sprite Kit's automatically generated atlas textures place it before the "@2x", and TexturePacker is placing it after. I sent an email to author, but I haven't heard back yet.

Comment: Looks like this has been fixed with the latest release (3.2.0).